# Is there a way to customize the ObjectMapper used by Spring MVC without returning String?

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I have a graph of objects that I'd like to return different views of. I don't want to use Jackson's `@JsonViews` to implement this. Right now, I use Jackson MixIn classes to configure which fields are shown. However, all my rest methods return a String rather than a type like `BusinessCategory` or `Collection< BusinessCategory >`. I can't figure out a way to dynamically configure the Jackson serializer based on what view I'd like of the data. Is there any feature built into Spring to configure which Jackson serializer to use on a per-function basis? I've found posts mentioning storing which fields you want in serialized in thread-local and having a filter send them and another post filtering based on Spring `@Role`, but nothing addressing choosing a serializer (or MixIn) on a per-function basis. Any ideas?

The key to me thinking a proposed solution is good is if the return type is an object, not String.

Here are the objects in my graph.

```
public class BusinessCategory implements Comparable<BusinessCategory> {
  private String name;
  private Set<BusinessCategory> parentCategories = new TreeSet<>();
  private Set<BusinessCategory> childCategories = new TreeSet<>();

  // getters, setters, compareTo, et cetera
}
```

I am sending these across the wire from a Spring MVC controller as JSON like so:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/business")
public class BusinessMVC {
  private Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder mapperBuilder;
  private ObjectMapper parentOnlyMapper;

  @Autowired
  public BusinessMVCfinal(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder mapperBuilder) {
    this.mapperBuilder = mapperBuilder;
    this.parentOnlyMapper = mapperBuilder.build();
    parentOnlyMapper.registerModule(new BusinessCategoryParentsOnlyMapperModule());
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/business_category/parents/{categoryName}")
  @ResponseBody
  public String getParentCategories(@PathVariable String categoryName) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return parentOnlyMapper.writeValueAsString(
        BusinessCategory.businessCategoryForName(categoryName));
  }
}
```

I have configure the serialization in a MixIn which is in turn added to the ObjectMapper using a module.

```
public interface BusinessCategoryParentsOnlyMixIn {
  @JsonProperty("name") String getName();
  @JsonProperty("parentCategories") Set<BusinessCategory> getParentCategories();
  @JsonIgnore Set<BusinessCategory> getChildCategories();
}

public class BusinessCategoryParentsOnlyMapperModule extends SimpleModule {
  public BusinessCategoryParentsOnlyMapperModule() {
    super("BusinessCategoryParentsOnlyMapperModule",
      new Version(1, 0, 0, "SNAPSHOT", "", ""));
  }

  public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
    context.setMixInAnnotations(
      BusinessCategory.class,
      BusinessCategoryParentsOnlyMixIn.class);
  }
}
```

My current solution works, it just doesn't feel very clean.

```
  "categories" : [ {
    "name" : "Personal Driver",
    "parentCategories" : [ {
      "name" : "Transportation",
      "parentCategories" : [ ]
    } ]
  }
```

Oh yes, I'm using:

- spring-boot 1.2.7
- spring-framework: 4.1.8
- jackson 2.6.3
- Others listed here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html

Comment: You don't want to use `@JsonViews` because you want to keep mapper configurations tied to the `@RequestMapping` methods somehow, right?

Comment: Yes, I want the JSON mapping config to be localized to the @RequestMapping methods (and associated mapping helpers). I *don't* want to create a new set of objects with just the data I want serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the only process that met my needs was to create a set of view objects which exposed only the fields I wanted to expose. In the grand scheme of things, it only added a small amount of seemingly unnecessary code to the project and made the flow of data easier to understand.